# sbt can not find the ebean dependency (Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes)

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I created new play-java application by using command from play [website](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/NewApplication)

```
sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8
```

Then added **EBean** dependencies like below ([link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaEbean)):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.1")
```

And see below message. How in sbt can I verify what exactly is wrong?

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-ebean;4.0.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean:4.0.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean:4.0.1 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/user/src/github/test-proj/project/plugins.sbt#L5-6)
[warn]        +- default:test-proj-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-ebean;4.0.1: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version `4.0.1` of `sbt-play-ebean` is not available for **Scala 2.12** and **Sbt 1.x**.

You should upgrade the `sbt-play-ebean` to `4.1.0` or at least to `4.0.6`.

For reference see [Bintray repo](https://bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/play-ebean)