# How to add Play Ebean in Play project?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I created web application using play framework. I am trying to use Play Ebean following this guide [Java Ebean - 2.6.x - Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaEbean). So I copied `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.1")` into plugins.sbt and modified build.sbt

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

But while running sbt it says it is unable to resolve dependencies.

> [warn]    Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
>   [error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:4.0.1
>   [error]   Not found
>   [error]   Not found
>   [error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-play-ebean_2.12_1.0/4.0.1/sbt-play-ebean-4.0.1.pom

After reading few other stackoverflow posts [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095957/sbt-can-not-find-the-ebean-dependency-some-unresolved-dependencies-have-extra-a), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201488/unresolved-dependencies-sbt-with-play-framework), it seems it is due to unmatched versions. I tried to use [sbt-play-ebean 6.1.0](https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean#releases), but it didn't work. Second link suggested changing scala version used by sbt, but I can't find how to do that.

Comment: Use 6.0.0, 6.1.0 not released yet.

Comment: @VM4 thank you it worked after using 6.0.0. I thought I had tried that but apparently I didn't. If you would answer it I'd be happy to mark it answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

6.0.0 is the newest supported version as of today.

Answer (score 1):

check the [play-ebean](https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean) site to know which version to use. In your case with Play 2.6.x you may use 4.0.2 -> 4.1.4. The error is actually because the 4.0.1 version is not found in the repo.